# how to bulkify the next apex code

Tags: apex, bulkification

I got the code below that I had to bulkify it. Basically we need to query campaign share record from a campaign when the cxampaign_approver(lookup to users) field is updated and then remove the manual sharing for the old approver.

This is not bulkify code:

```
List<CampaignShare> Deletemanualshare = new List<CampaignShare>();
for (Campaign newCampaign : Trigger.newMap.values())
{
    Campaign oldCampaign = Trigger.oldMap.get(newCampaign.Id);
    if (oldCampaign != null && oldCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c != newCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c)
    {
        for (CampaignShare Shareoldapprover : [SELECT Id FROM CampaignShare WHERE CampaignId = :oldCampaign.Id AND UserOrGroupId = :oldCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c AND RowCause = :Schema.CampaignShare.RowCause.Manual])
            Deletemanualshare.add(Shareoldapprover);
    }
}
delete Deletemanualshare;
```

So I bulkify it in the way below but my question is since I am still learning is there any better practice to bulkify that code than the one below?

```
List<CampaignShare> Deletemanualshare = new List<CampaignShare>();
List<campaign> approverupdatedcampaigns = new list<Campaign>();
set<id> alloldapproversId = new set<id>();
set<id> affectedcampa = new set<id>();
for (Campaign newCampaign : Trigger.newMap.values())
{
    Campaign oldCampaign = Trigger.oldMap.get(newCampaign.Id);
    if (oldCampaign != null && oldCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c != newCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c)
    {
            approverupdatedcampaigns.add(oldCampaign);
        alloldapproversId.add(oldCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c);
        affectedcampa.add(oldCampaign.Id);
    }
}
List<CampaignShare> Shareoldapprover = new List<CampaignShare>();
if(approverupdatedcampaigns.size()>0){
        Shareoldapprover = [SELECT Id,CampaignId,UserOrGroupId FROM CampaignShare WHERE CampaignId in : affectedcampa AND UserOrGroupId in : alloldapproversId AND RowCause = 'Manual'];
}
for(CampaignShare CS : Shareoldapprover) {
    for(campaign camp :approverupdatedcampaigns){
        if(CS.CampaignId == camp.id && CS.UserOrGroupId == camp.Campaign_Approver__c){
            Deletemanualshare.add(CS);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
if(Deletemanualshare.size()>0)
    delete Deletemanualshare;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have optimised the code little further:-

1. I have changed the `List<campaign> approverupdatedcampaigns = new list<Campaign>();` to  `Map<id,campaign> approverupdatedcampaigns = new map<id,Campaign>();` It eliminates the nested for loop which can save you from **apex cpu time limit exceeded**.
2. Instead of checking null as `Deletemanualshare.size()>0`, I have done it in `!Deletemanualshare.isEmpty()`
3. I have eliminated `set<id> affectedcampa = new set<id>();` as i can get the same set of id from `Map<id,campaign> approverupdatedcampaigns = new map<id,Campaign>();`

> Find the updated code here:-

```
    List<CampaignShare> Deletemanualshare = new List<CampaignShare>();
    Map<id,campaign> approverupdatedcampaigns = new map<id,Campaign>();
    set<id> alloldapproversId = new set<id>();
    for (Campaign newCampaign : Trigger.newMap.values())
    {
        Campaign oldCampaign = Trigger.oldMap.get(newCampaign.Id);
        if (oldCampaign != null && oldCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c != newCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c)
        {
            approverupdatedcampaigns.put(oldCampaign.id,oldCampaign);
            alloldapproversId.add(oldCampaign.Campaign_Approver__c);
        }
    }
    List<CampaignShare> Shareoldapprover = new List<CampaignShare>();
    if(!approverupdatedcampaigns.Keyset().isEmpty()){
            Shareoldapprover = [SELECT Id,CampaignId,UserOrGroupId FROM CampaignShare WHERE CampaignId in : approverupdatedcampaigns.keyset() AND UserOrGroupId in : alloldapproversId AND RowCause = 'Manual'];
    }
    for(CampaignShare CS : Shareoldapprover) {
        if(approverupdatedcampaigns.containsKey(CS.CampaignId)){
            if(CS.UserOrGroupId == approverupdatedcampaigns.get(CS.CampaignId).Campaign_Approver__c){
                Deletemanualshare.add(CS);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!Deletemanualshare.isEmpty()){
        delete Deletemanualshare;
    }
```